# Accessing a SQL Server on host's network from a virtual machine

Tags: sql-server, linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox

My company has a set up where there is a Microsoft SQL Server accessible on our local network (no internet access) that I can access from my normal workstation (running Windows 10). On this workstation I have installed an Ubuntu virtual machine with Virtualbox, and this virtual machine serves as my main development platform. I would like to

- Be able to access the SQL Server from the guest with python
- Ideally, I would also like to use the host's Windows Authentication for the SQL Server, although this is optional

How should I set this up? I have no control over the SQL Server (but I could maybe sweet talk the engineers into some small changes), but I have some control over the host and full control over the guest. Should the virtual network be NAT or bridged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question in case other people have the same problem. The following is tested with an Ubuntu client in a NAT configuration on a Windows host. I strongly suggest using the same username on both the Linux client and the Windows host.

I found most of the solution by following this excellent guide: http://www.easysoft.com/products/data_access/odbc-sql-server-driver/kerberos.html.

You can possibly find the Key Distribution Center (KDC) by looking for your local DNS server `nmcli dev show | grep DNS` (that worked for me), otherwise ask your local IT department.

On the Windows host - that should have access to the SQL Server - you can list Server Principal Names (SPNs) by entering `setspn -L` in a Windows command prompt.

Instead of the EasySoft driver I used Microsoft's own ODBC driver: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server. Make sure that unixODBC is also installed.

Remember that domains should be in all caps (for reasons I don't fully understand) when configuring kerberos in /etc/krb5.conf.

Regarding the section **Configuring an SQL Server ODBC Data Source for Kerberos Authentication** you can use the driver name specified in /etc/odbcinst.ini that was added when you installed the Microsoft ODBC driver. My odbcinst.ini looks like this

```
[ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]
Description=Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Driver=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.1.so.9.1
UsageCount=1
```

and so  the /etc/odbc.ini should look like (refer to Easysoft's guide for the meaning of `windowsmachine` and `spn`)

```
[mssql-kerberos-dsn]
Driver                  = ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server
Server                  = windowsmachine
ServerSPN               = spn
Trusted_Connnection     = yes
```

Note the additional line `Trusted_Connnection`. This makes the data source slightly more convenient to use.

Before testing the setup you have to run `kinit` and login with your Active Directory credentials as explained in Easysoft's guide. You can then test the connection with `

```
sqlcmd -D -S mssql-kerberos-dsn
```

if you have sqlcmd installed (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools).

Furthermore, you can test if it works with pyodbc by running

```
import pyodbc 
print(pyodbc.connect('DSN=mssql-kerberos-dsn'))
```

from a python terminal.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/227505/105108) about the differences between NAT and bridged network on VMware. For Virtualbox they should be the same.

Basically bridged network has less limits on how network operates then NAT. So if you have access to SQL Server from host, you will have the same access from guest with bridged network.

Answer (score 0):

to me, cleaner way is installing ubuntu as host and use docker to host your SQL Server. Also, look for how to join ubuntu to windows AD. It will help you configuring the users.